# How to store output of itertools query

Tags: python

I have below query

```
for key, group in itertools.groupby(r, lambda item: item['b_id']):
        print {key: [x['a_id'] for x in group]}
```

that gives the output

```
{'0d687c94c5f4': ['12345', '67890']}
{'9ec34be3d535': ['23857', '84596']}
{None: ['d82ebe9815cc']}
```

How to store this to a variable to access its contents

tried data = {key: [x['a_id'] for x in group]} but gives only last value from loop which is {None: ['d82ebe9815cc']}

```
>>data 
>>{None: ['d82ebe9815cc']}
```

Comment: You could do: `data = {k:[el['a_id'] for el in g] for k, g in itertools.groupby(...)}`. but fairly sure there's a fairly good post on storing output from groupby I can't find right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new dictionary with a single key at each iteration. Instead, define a dictionary first, then add keys in the loop:

```
data = {}

for key, group in itertools.groupby(r, lambda item: item['b_id']):
    data[key] = [x['a_id'] for x in group]
```

Alternatively, you can use a dictionary comprehension (Python 2.7+):

```
data = {key: [x['a_id'] for x in group] for key, group in
        itertools.groupby(r, lambda item: item['b_id'])}
```